# Android Black Glossy Header/Footer View?

Tags: android

In the Gmail app on my HTC Android phone, the headers are glossy black, much like the header on an iPhone.

Is there a setting on a view that I can use to create this background look, or is it a graphic they are over laying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Gmail app does not provide such graphics, nor does the UI toolkit. It looks like a change HTC made to the theme/app. If you want to do the same in your app, you'll have to do it on your own.